# Is there a way to count the number of characters from a certain word in a given string in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find a way to count the number of chars in a certain word starting with a certain char from a given string in c# using only system.

So for example for the following string `"the weather outside is beautiful"`. If I want to count the number of chars for the word "outside" using as a rule just the first letter (in this case will be "o"), can I count somehow the number of chars preceding the o? (in this case will be 6).

I was thinking that it should be something like:

If word starts with "o" than count the following chars and stop counting when we find space, return number.

I tried finding something similar but unfortunately I wasn't successful.

As an addition, there will be only one word starting with the letter o. (or another letter which will be used as a finding rule)

I hope the question is clear enough and thank you in advance!

Comment: Split string by spaces - you get a list of words. Check first letter of each word, take those that are `'o'`. get the lenght of those words. Where is your code? [mre] - did you research anything? [ask] ?

Comment: This was so obvious. Was searching for something complicated, thank you!

Comment: I tried to read this question, and stull confused as why to return `6`. You want "number of chars **preceding** the o". Preceding means: "coming before something in order", so you want to count characters in "the weather "? Which are 12 characters, or 7 unique characters.   I do not know why you start "If word starts with "o" than count the following chars" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach would be to

- Split() string by spaces: you get a list of words
- iterate list and check first letter of each word
- if word starts with 'o': get the lenght of word

you can do this either using `String.Split()` - leveraging `System.Linq`, or even by using simple loops.

### Using loops:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "the weather outside is beautiful";
        
        var word = "";
        foreach( var l in text)
        {
            if (word == "" && l == 'o')
            {
                word += l;
            } 
            else if (word != ""  && l == ' ')
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}",
                                         word, word.Length));
                word = "";
            }
            else if (word != "")
            {
                word += l;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This (and the others) output:

```
outside : 7
```

### Using `String.Split()`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "the weather outside is beautiful";

        var words = text.Split(' ');
        
        foreach( var w in words)
        {
            if (w.StartsWith("o"))
                System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}",
                                         w, w.Length));
        }
    }
}
```

### Using Linq:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "the weather outside is beautiful";
        
        var splitted = text
            .Split(' ')
            .Where(w => w.StartsWith("o", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        
        foreach(var w in splitted)
            System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", w, w.Length));      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use `Regex`:

```
var text = "the weather outside is beautiful";
var regex = new Regex(@"(o.*?)\b");
var length = regex.Match(text).Captures[0].Length;
Console.WriteLine(length);
```

That gives `7`.